# How can I test if my USB ports are working correctly?

Tags: windows-7, usb, 64-bit

I have a Sabertooth P67-B3 motherboard, and I *think* my USB ports might not be working correctly, but I'm not 100% sure.  The BIOS version is 1502 (American Megatrends).

When I go to Device Manager, everything looks fine.  No yellow warning boxes.

The problem comes from not being able to connect my I-Phone 3.  The charge light on the phone comes on when it connects, so it recharges, but I-Tunes won't recognize the phone being attached.  Apple support says to keep uninstalling I-Tunes and reinstalling it, but that hasn't worked for me.  The Apple Mobile Device USB Driver does not show up in Device Manager.

But also, my daughter got a LeapPad for Christmas, and that has the same symptoms.  When I connect the LeapPad, it dings, tries to connect, then fails and says to install the software on the PC (which is already installed).

So I'm beginning to think the USB ports maybe aren't quite right.  How can I test that the USB ports are working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that USB ports are working correctly as PC is trying to get a driver. In any case you can connect any simpler devices to it - like flash drive.
I believe the problem is in the software side.

Comment: Yes, connecting USB flash drives work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a specific motherboard (instead of a specific computer), may I assume that this was a home-build?  Are these USB ports connected directly to the motherboard, or are they on the case connected to headers on the motherboard?  Especially if the later, it sounds like the 2 power pins are correctly connected, but that the data pins are either reversed - or one of them is disconnected.

Comment: Correct, my first home built attempt.  Good point about the data pins.  I'll have to power down and look later today.  Note however, I have a USB flash drive on my keychain, and that still works when I connect it.